# pgfplot x-axis with constant positions

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have some pretty simple measurement data, that I want to visualize on a graph.

In order to get started, I grabbed an example.
I have some measurements on the x-axis, that is ordered as 1,4,16,64,256,1024, and I want these to be on the same x-axis, in with the same distance between each other

my current latex looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.9}

% We will externalize the figures
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Mah depending on DHRP interval},
    xlabel={DHRP interval},
    ylabel={Mah over five hours},
    xmin=0, xmax=1024,
    ymin=400, ymax=700,
    xtick={1,4,16,64,256,1024},
    ytick={400,450,500,550,600,650,700},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[
    color=blue,
    mark=square,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (1,500)(4,520)(16,540)(64,550)(256,560)(1024,670)
    };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This gives me the following graph:

[image]

and here, the issue is that each point on the x-axis, is spread out to it's relative position, dependning on it's numerical value.

Is there any way I can put them in their "absolute" position, so their value do not determine where on the line they are lying?

Comment: My compiled result is different to the attached image: the plot is blue, goes through dots like `(64,550)` and `(1024,670)`, and without legends.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `symbolic x coords` to solve your problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.18}

% SI units: celsius and gram
\usepackage{siunitx}

% externalize figures
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={?},
    xlabel={Temperature [\unit{\celsius}]},
    ylabel={Solubility [\unit{\gram} per \SI{100}{\gram} water]},
    symbolic x coords={1,4,16,64,256,1024},% <- set correct x ticks
    ymin=400, ymax=700,
    ytick={400,450,500,550,600,650,700},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed
]

\addplot[mark=square]
    coordinates {
        (1,500)
        (4,520)
        (16,540)
        (64,550)
        (256,560)
        (1024,670)
    };
\addlegendentry{CuSO\textsubscript{4}$\cdot$5H\textsubscript{2}O};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]